# os.listdir() in python breaks when called from PHP exec() in OSX

Tags: php, python, macos

I am trying to run a python script from php using exec() like below:

```
exec("python '/path/to/mp.py' '".$arg1."' '".$arg2."'",$my_output, $r);
```

The python code is to aggregate all mp3 files I have in my mac and play.
I have written below code for this, which works fine when run directly from terminal or through a shell script.

```
import os
def getMusic(baseDirU):

    baseDir = baseDirU
    dirs = os.listdir(baseDir)

    if len(dirs) == 0:
        return

    for f in os.listdir(baseDir):
        if(f == ".DS_Store" or len(f) == 0):
            continue

        f = f.split(".mp3")
        if len(f) == 2:
            audio_file = baseDir + "/" + ".mp3".join(f)
            getMusic.musicFiles.append(audio_file)
        else:
            f = "".join(f)
            oldDir = baseDir
            baseDir = baseDir + "/" + f
            getMusic(baseDir)
            baseDir = oldDir

def main():
    print sys.path
    baseDir = sys.argv[1]
    searchedSong = sys.argv[2]
    if baseDir == "":
        print("No Base file given, Exitting")
        sys.exit()

    getMusic.musicFiles = []
    getMusic(baseDir)

    playMusic.subP = 0
    playMusic(searchedSong)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When this piece of code is getting executed using PHP exec(), I debugged and get to know that some how it stops execution at os.listdir() statement inside getMusic().

May be user(www-data) running php exec() command does not have access to run os commands or some other reason!! if inaccessibility is the issue, let me know how to give access to www-data?

Comment: Check the output of `ls -l` on the directory you are running `os.listdir` on for permissions.

Comment: Permissions. Which user runs your php, what permissions to they have?

Comment: I run php code from browser, rest I don't know. I am sorry.

Comment: @Elliott ls -l will check permission on current directory related thing, How can I check there for os.listdir?? And I gave full permission to the python file I am executing.

Comment: If python can't execute `os.listdir()`, it must be throwing an exception. By using a try statement, you could perhaps write the exception traceback in a file.

Comment: ohh great..  Very good Idea. Here is the issue, Please let me know how to fix this, It does not occur in terminal.  `"OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/jyotirmaysenapati/Desktop/Music'"` @Gribouillis

Comment: It's very simple, the user does not have the permission to list the directory. It's not a python issue, it is an OS issue. Configure permissions, users and groups the right way! Python can display the user and group and probably the permissions.